# CardContent mui not responding to bgcolor transparent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have following a course which used mui v4 and since a lot changed from v4 to v5, I can't get all the styles although i managed and did my best and i am really stuck here.

This is my FeaturedMovie.jsx component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Typography, Box, Card, CardContent, CardMedia, styled } from '@mui/material';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const CardTypography = styled(CardContent)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: '#fff',
  width: '40%',
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
    width: '100%',
  },
}));

function FeaturedMovie({ movie }) {
  if (!movie) return null;
  return (
    <Box sx={{ marginBottom: '20px', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', height: '490px', textDecoration: 'none' }} component={Link} to={`/movie/${movie.id}`}>
      <Card sx={{ ':root': { position: 'relative' }, width: '100%', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
        <CardMedia
          sx={{ position: 'relative', top: 0, right: 0, height: '100%', width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.575)', backgroundBlendMode: 'darken' }}
          media="picture"
          alt={movie.title}
          image={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${movie?.backdrop_path}`}
          title={movie.title}
        />
        <Box padding="20px" bgcolor="black">
          <CardTypography>
            <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>{movie.title}</Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2">{movie.overview}</Typography>
          </CardTypography>
        </Box>
      </Card>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default FeaturedMovie;
```

I tried changing the bgcolor of the Box but it's not becoming transparent instead becomes white,
i tried overiding the root styling but nothing seems to work.

I want the CardTypography(CardContent) to have position relative and bgcolor transparent,
in the course the guy overides the root styles using classes prop and gives styles to the root but in v6 the same can't be done (there is nothing in the documentations).

Currently it looks like this [cardcontent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ8Gg.jpg) and i want it to look like this [card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRMCm.jpg) also i am using mui v5.15.4

Help me out here if someone knows how to do this.

Comment: which version of mui are you using ?

Comment: Currently. [this is how it looks like](https://i.ibb.co/TkQZ7rV/image.png). What do you want to change? is [this](https://i.ibb.co/BcFfRW3/image.png) what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to write on top of the image? You have to play with the css zIndexes and positions.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Typography, Box, Card, CardContent, CardMedia, styled } from '@mui/material'

const CardTypography = styled(CardContent)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: '#fff',
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  width: '100%',
}))

export function FeaturedMovie({ movie }) {
  if (!movie) return null
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{ marginBottom: '20px', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', height: '490px', textDecoration: 'none' }}
    >
      <Card
        sx={{
          position: 'relative',
          width: '100%',
          display: 'flex',
          justifyContent: 'flex-end',
          flexDirection: 'column',
        }}
      >
        <CardMedia
          sx={{
            zIndex: 0,
            position: 'absolute',
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.575)',
            backgroundBlendMode: 'darken',
          }}
          image={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${movie?.backdrop_path}`}
          title={movie.title}
        />
        <Box padding="20px" sx={{ zIndex: 1 }}>
          <CardTypography>
            <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
              {movie.title}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2">{movie.overview}</Typography>
          </CardTypography>
        </Box>
      </Card>
    </Box>
  )
}

export default FeaturedMovie
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot fam, this is exactly what i was looking for just a little mishap in the mobile view. it looks like this https://imgur.com/VNbXD4a . please help out with this also

Comment: @AugustaBhardwaj, on the `<CardTypography/>` styled component, you're specifying `width: "40%"`, just remove that and make it `width: "100%"`